# Crash When Adding a Memory Layer

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I am working on a QGIS plugin that has two modules attached with feature selection signal. One shows the attribute and the other one adds polygon segments with other functions. The polygon segments are on memory layer with the code below. The crash happens when addMapLayer/addMapLayers is called.

```
def create_temporary_layer(source_layer, type, name, show_legend=True, style=True):
    # create a new memory layer
    crs = source_layer.crs()
    crs_id = crs.srsid()
    wkt = crs.toWkt()
    vl_geom_config = u"{0}?crs={1}&field=name:string(20)&" \
                     u"index=yes".format(type, wkt)

    v_layer = QgsVectorLayer(vl_geom_config, name, "memory")

    target_crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(
        crs_id, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.InternalCrsId
    )

    v_layer.setCrs(target_crs)

    iface.mapCanvas().mapSettings().setDestinationCrs(target_crs)

    iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
    if style:
        if type == 'LineString':
            symbols = v_layer.rendererV2().symbols2(QgsRenderContext())
            symbol = symbols[0]
            symbol.setWidth(2)

        if type == 'Point':
            symbols = v_layer.rendererV2().symbols2(QgsRenderContext())
            symbol = symbols[0]
            symbol.setSize(4)

    # show the line 
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(   # The crash happens here. 
        v_layer, show_legend
    )

    v_layer.updateExtents()

    return v_layer
```

It works find when the attribute showing module is not active. However, when both are active, QGIS crashes with the following crash dump (Removed entries of windows files due to page limit).

```
Dump Summary
------------
Dump File:  qgis-20180716-074516-31024-25832-9fba24a3f2.dmp : C:\Users\Wondim\AppData\Local\Temp\qgis-20180716-074516-31024-25832-9fba24a3f2.dmp
Last Write Time:    7/16/2018 7:45:17 AM
Process Name:   qgis-ltr-bin.exe : C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\qgis-ltr-bin.exe
Process Architecture:   x64
Exception Code: 0xC0000005
Exception Information:  The thread tried to read from or write to a virtual address for which it does not have the appropriate access.
Heap Information:   Not Present

System Information
------------------
OS Version: 10.0.17134
CLR Version(s): 

Modules
-------
Module Name Module Path Module Version
----------- ----------- --------------
qgis-ltr-bin.exe    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\qgis-ltr-bin.exe 0.0.0.0

qgis_app.dll    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\qgis-ltr\bin\qgis_app.dll   0.0.0.0
shell32.dll C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll 6.2.17134.137
QtCore4.dll C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\QtCore4.dll  4.8.5.0
powrprof.dll    C:\Windows\System32\powrprof.dll    6.2.17134.1
fltLib.dll  C:\Windows\System32\fltLib.dll  6.2.17134.1
QtGui4.dll  C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\QtGui4.dll   4.8.5.0
comdlg32.dll    C:\Windows\System32\comdlg32.dll    6.2.17134.1
oleaut32.dll    C:\Windows\System32\oleaut32.dll    6.2.17134.48
msvcp100.dll    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\msvcp100.dll 10.0.40219.1
imm32.dll   C:\Windows\System32\imm32.dll   6.2.17134.1
msvcr100.dll    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\msvcr100.dll 10.0.40219.1
zlib1.dll   C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\zlib1.dll    1.2.8.0
qwt5.dll    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\qwt5.dll 5.2.3.0
QtSql4.dll  C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\QtSql4.dll   4.8.5.0
QtWebKit4.dll   C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\QtWebKit4.dll    4.9.4.0
gdal202.dll C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\gdal202.dll  2.2.4.0
psapi.dll   C:\Windows\System32\psapi.dll   6.2.17134.1
qgis_analysis.dll   C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\qgis-ltr\bin\qgis_analysis.dll  0.0.0.0
qscintilla2.dll C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\qscintilla2.dll  0.0.0.0
qgis_core.dll   C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\qgis-ltr\bin\qgis_core.dll  0.0.0.0
qgis_gui.dll    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\qgis-ltr\bin\qgis_gui.dll   0.0.0.0
QtXml4.dll  C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\QtXml4.dll   4.8.5.0
QtNetwork4.dll  C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\QtNetwork4.dll   4.8.5.0
QtSvg4.dll  C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\QtSvg4.dll   4.8.5.0
comctl32.dll    C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.17134.165_none_f954469b3093f6d5\comctl32.dll    5.82.17134.165

ogdi.dll    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\ogdi.dll 0.0.0.0
expat.dll   C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\expat.dll    0.0.0.0
libpq.dll   C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\libpq.dll    9.2.4.13228

jpeg.dll    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\jpeg.dll 0.0.0.0
netcdf.dll  C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\netcdf.dll   0.0.0.0
libmysql.dll    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\libmysql.dll 6.1.9.0
hdf5.dll    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\hdf5.dll 0.0.0.0
libcurl.dll C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\libcurl.dll  7.54.0.0
normaliz.dll    C:\Windows\System32\normaliz.dll    6.2.17134.1
openjp2.dll C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\openjp2.dll  0.0.0.0
xerces-c_3_2.dll    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\xerces-c_3_2.dll 3.2.0.0
iconv-2.dll C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\iconv-2.dll  1.15.0.0
freexl.dll  C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\freexl.dll   0.0.0.0

liblzma.dll C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\liblzma.dll  5.2.3.0
qca.dll C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\qca.dll  0.0.0.0
geos_c.dll  C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\geos_c.dll   0.0.0.0
secur32.dll C:\Windows\System32\secur32.dll 6.2.17134.1
WINMMBASE.dll   C:\Windows\System32\WINMMBASE.dll   6.2.17134.1
propsys.dll C:\Windows\System32\propsys.dll 7.0.17134.112
spatialindex-64.dll C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\spatialindex-64.dll  0.0.0.0
IPHLPAPI.DLL    C:\Windows\System32\IPHLPAPI.DLL    6.2.17134.1
bcrypt.dll  C:\Windows\System32\bcrypt.dll  6.2.17134.112
lwgeom.dll  C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\lwgeom.dll   0.0.0.0
iconv.dll   C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\iconv.dll    0.0.0.0
proj.dll    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\proj.dll 0.0.0.0
hdf5_hl.dll C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\hdf5_hl.dll  0.0.0.0
ssleay32.dll    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\ssleay32.dll 1.0.2.10
szip.dll    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\szip.dll 0.0.0.0

libxml2.dll C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\libxml2.dll  0.0.0.0
sspicli.dll C:\Windows\System32\sspicli.dll 6.2.17134.1
libeay32.dll    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\libeay32.dll 1.0.2.10

qgif4.dll   C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Qt4\plugins\imageformats\qgif4.dll  4.8.5.0
qico4.dll   C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Qt4\plugins\imageformats\qico4.dll  4.8.5.0
qjpeg4.dll  C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Qt4\plugins\imageformats\qjpeg4.dll 4.8.5.0
qmng4.dll   C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Qt4\plugins\imageformats\qmng4.dll  4.8.5.0
qsvg4.dll   C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Qt4\plugins\imageformats\qsvg4.dll  4.8.5.0
qtga4.dll   C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Qt4\plugins\imageformats\qtga4.dll  4.8.5.0
qtiff4.dll  C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Qt4\plugins\imageformats\qtiff4.dll 4.8.5.0
libtiff.dll C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\libtiff.dll  0.0.0.0
jpeg12.dll  C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\jpeg12.dll   0.0.0.0
qsvgicon4.dll   C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Qt4\plugins\iconengines\qsvgicon4.dll   4.8.5.0
CRYPTBASE.DLL   C:\Windows\System32\CRYPTBASE.DLL   6.2.17134.1
qca-gnupg.dll   C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Qt4\plugins\crypto\qca-gnupg.dll    0.0.0.0
qca-logger.dll  C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Qt4\plugins\crypto\qca-logger.dll   0.0.0.0
qca-ossl.dll    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Qt4\plugins\crypto\qca-ossl.dll 0.0.0.0
qca-softstore.dll   C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Qt4\plugins\crypto\qca-softstore.dll    0.0.0.0

basicauthmethod.dll C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\qgis-ltr\plugins\basicauthmethod.dll    0.0.0.0
identcertauthmethod.dll C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\qgis-ltr\plugins\identcertauthmethod.dll    0.0.0.0
pkcs12authmethod.dll    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\qgis-ltr\plugins\pkcs12authmethod.dll   0.0.0.0
pkipathsauthmethod.dll  C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\qgis-ltr\plugins\pkipathsauthmethod.dll 0.0.0.0
qsqlite4.dll    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Qt4\plugins\sqldrivers\qsqlite4.dll 4.8.5.0
qgenericbearer4.dll C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Qt4\plugins\bearer\qgenericbearer4.dll  4.8.5.0
nsi.dll C:\Windows\System32\nsi.dll 6.2.17134.1
dhcpcsvc.dll    C:\Windows\System32\dhcpcsvc.dll    6.2.17134.1
dhcpcsvc6.DLL   C:\Windows\System32\dhcpcsvc6.DLL   6.2.17134.1
qnativewifibearer4.dll  C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Qt4\plugins\bearer\qnativewifibearer4.dll   4.8.5.0
wlanapi.dll C:\Windows\System32\wlanapi.dll 6.2.17134.1
mswsock.dll C:\Windows\System32\mswsock.dll 6.2.17134.1
dnsapi.dll  C:\Windows\System32\dnsapi.dll  6.2.17134.165
rasadhlp.dll    C:\Windows\System32\rasadhlp.dll    6.2.17134.1
edputil.dll C:\Windows\System32\edputil.dll 6.2.17134.1
arcgisfeatureserverprovider.dll C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\qgis-ltr\plugins\arcgisfeatureserverprovider.dll    0.0.0.0
qjson.dll   C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\qjson.dll    0.0.0.0
arcgismapserverprovider.dll C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\qgis-ltr\plugins\arcgismapserverprovider.dll    0.0.0.0
coordinatecaptureplugin.dll C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\qgis-ltr\plugins\coordinatecaptureplugin.dll    0.0.0.0
db2provider.dll C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\qgis-ltr\plugins\db2provider.dll    0.0.0.0
delimitedtextprovider.dll   C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\qgis-ltr\plugins\delimitedtextprovider.dll  0.0.0.0
dxf2shpconverterplugin.dll  C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\qgis-ltr\plugins\dxf2shpconverterplugin.dll 0.0.0.0
evis.dll    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\qgis-ltr\plugins\evis.dll   0.0.0.0
gdalprovider.dll    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\qgis-ltr\plugins\gdalprovider.dll   0.0.0.0
gdal_ECW_JP2ECW.dll C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\gdalplugins\gdal_ECW_JP2ECW.dll  0.0.0.0
NCSEcw.dll  C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\NCSEcw.dll   5.3.0.862
imagehlp.dll    C:\Windows\System32\imagehlp.dll    6.2.17134.1
gdal_GEOR.dll   C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\gdalplugins\gdal_GEOR.dll    0.0.0.0
oci.dll C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\oci.dll  12.1.0.0
gdal_MG4Lidar.dll   C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\gdalplugins\gdal_MG4Lidar.dll    0.0.0.0
lti_lidar_dsdk_1.1.dll  C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\lti_lidar_dsdk_1.1.dll   1.1.4.4703
tbb.dll C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\tbb.dll  4.1.0.0
gdal_MrSID.dll  C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\gdalplugins\gdal_MrSID.dll   0.0.0.0
lti_dsdk_9.5.dll    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\lti_dsdk_9.5.dll 9.5.4.4703
ogr_OCI.dll C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\gdalplugins\ogr_OCI.dll  0.0.0.0
ogr_SOSI.dll    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\gdalplugins\ogr_SOSI.dll 0.0.0.0
geometrycheckerplugin.dll   C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\qgis-ltr\plugins\geometrycheckerplugin.dll  0.0.0.0
geometrysnapperplugin.dll   C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\qgis-ltr\plugins\geometrysnapperplugin.dll  0.0.0.0
georefplugin.dll    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\qgis-ltr\plugins\georefplugin.dll   0.0.0.0
gsl.dll C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\gsl.dll  0.0.0.0
cblas.dll   C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\cblas.dll    0.0.0.0
globeplugin.dll C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\qgis-ltr\plugins\globeplugin.dll    0.0.0.0
QtOpenGL4.dll   C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\QtOpenGL4.dll    4.8.5.0
osg97-osgUtil.dll   C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\osg97-osgUtil.dll    3.1.7.97
osg97-osgQt.dll C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\osg97-osgQt.dll  3.1.7.97
osg97-osgViewer.dll C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\osg97-osgViewer.dll  3.1.7.97
osgEarth.dll    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\osgEarth.dll 0.0.0.0
osg97-osgGA.dll C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\osg97-osgGA.dll  3.1.7.97
osgEarthFeatures.dll    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\osgEarthFeatures.dll 0.0.0.0
osgEarthUtil.dll    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\osgEarthUtil.dll 0.0.0.0
osgEarthSymbology.dll   C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\osgEarthSymbology.dll    0.0.0.0
osgEarthQt.dll  C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\osgEarthQt.dll   0.0.0.0
ot12-OpenThreads.dll    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\ot12-OpenThreads.dll 2.6.0.12
opengl32.dll    C:\Windows\System32\opengl32.dll    6.2.17134.1
osg97-osgDB.dll C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\osg97-osgDB.dll  3.1.7.97
osg97-osgText.dll   C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\osg97-osgText.dll    3.1.7.97
osg97-osg.dll   C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\osg97-osg.dll    3.1.7.97
osg97-osgTerrain.dll    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\osg97-osgTerrain.dll 3.1.7.97
gdal200.dll C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\gdal200.dll  2.0.2.0
osg97-osgSim.dll    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\osg97-osgSim.dll 3.1.7.97
osgEarthAnnotation.dll  C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\osgEarthAnnotation.dll   0.0.0.0
osg97-osgShadow.dll C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\osg97-osgShadow.dll  3.1.7.97
glu32.dll   C:\Windows\System32\glu32.dll   6.2.17134.1
geotiff.dll C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\geotiff.dll  0.0.0.0
osg97-osgManipulator.dll    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\osg97-osgManipulator.dll 3.1.7.97
xerces-c_3_1.dll    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\xerces-c_3_1.dll 3.1.1.0
gpsimporterplugin.dll   C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\qgis-ltr\plugins\gpsimporterplugin.dll  0.0.0.0
gpxprovider.dll C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\qgis-ltr\plugins\gpxprovider.dll    0.0.0.0
heatmapplugin.dll   C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\qgis-ltr\plugins\heatmapplugin.dll  0.0.0.0
interpolationplugin.dll C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\qgis-ltr\plugins\interpolationplugin.dll    0.0.0.0
memoryprovider.dll  C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\qgis-ltr\plugins\memoryprovider.dll 0.0.0.0
mssqlprovider.dll   C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\qgis-ltr\plugins\mssqlprovider.dll  0.0.0.0
offlineeditingplugin.dll    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\qgis-ltr\plugins\offlineeditingplugin.dll   0.0.0.0
ogrprovider.dll C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\qgis-ltr\plugins\ogrprovider.dll    0.0.0.0
oracleplugin.dll    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\qgis-ltr\plugins\oracleplugin.dll   0.0.0.0
oracleprovider.dll  C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\qgis-ltr\plugins\oracleprovider.dll 0.0.0.0
owsprovider.dll C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\qgis-ltr\plugins\owsprovider.dll    0.0.0.0
postgresprovider.dll    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\qgis-ltr\plugins\postgresprovider.dll   0.0.0.0
rasterterrainplugin.dll C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\qgis-ltr\plugins\rasterterrainplugin.dll    0.0.0.0
roadgraphplugin.dll C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\qgis-ltr\plugins\roadgraphplugin.dll    0.0.0.0
qgis_networkanalysis.dll    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\qgis-ltr\bin\qgis_networkanalysis.dll   0.0.0.0
spatialiteprovider.dll  C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\qgis-ltr\plugins\spatialiteprovider.dll 0.0.0.0
spatialqueryplugin.dll  C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\qgis-ltr\plugins\spatialqueryplugin.dll 0.0.0.0
topolplugin.dll C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\qgis-ltr\plugins\topolplugin.dll    0.0.0.0
virtuallayerprovider.dll    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\qgis-ltr\plugins\virtuallayerprovider.dll   0.0.0.0
wcsprovider.dll C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\qgis-ltr\plugins\wcsprovider.dll    0.0.0.0
wfsprovider.dll C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\qgis-ltr\plugins\wfsprovider.dll    0.0.0.0
wmsprovider.dll C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\qgis-ltr\plugins\wmsprovider.dll    0.0.0.0
QtScript4.dll   C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\QtScript4.dll    4.8.5.0
zonalstatisticsplugin.dll   C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\qgis-ltr\plugins\zonalstatisticsplugin.dll  0.0.0.0
qgispython.DLL  C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\qgis-ltr\bin\qgispython.DLL 0.0.0.0
python27.dll    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\python27.dll 2.7.14150.1013
msvcr90.dll C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.9415_none_08e0c10ba840a28a\msvcr90.dll    9.0.30729.9415
sip.pyd C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\sip.pyd  0.0.0.0
QtCore.pyd  C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\QtCore.pyd 0.0.0.0
QtGui.pyd   C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\QtGui.pyd  0.0.0.0
_core.pyd   C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\qgis-ltr\python\qgis\_core.pyd  0.0.0.0
QtSql.pyd   C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\QtSql.pyd  0.0.0.0
QtNetwork.pyd   C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\QtNetwork.pyd  0.0.0.0
QtXml.pyd   C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\QtXml.pyd  0.0.0.0
_gui.pyd    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\qgis-ltr\python\qgis\_gui.pyd   0.0.0.0
Qsci.pyd    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\Qsci.pyd   0.0.0.0
_socket.pyd C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\DLLs\_socket.pyd   0.0.0.0
_ssl.pyd    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\DLLs\_ssl.pyd  0.0.0.0
_hashlib.pyd    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd  0.0.0.0
_ctypes.pyd C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\DLLs\_ctypes.pyd   0.0.0.0
bz2.pyd C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\DLLs\bz2.pyd   0.0.0.0
QtWebKit.pyd    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\QtWebKit.pyd   0.0.0.0
_gdal.pyd   C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\osgeo\_gdal.pyd  0.0.0.0
_ogr.pyd    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\osgeo\_ogr.pyd   0.0.0.0
_osr.pyd    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\osgeo\_osr.pyd   0.0.0.0
select.pyd  C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\DLLs\select.pyd    0.0.0.0
_speedups.pyd   C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\simplejson\_speedups.pyd 0.0.0.0
NapiNSP.dll C:\Windows\System32\NapiNSP.dll 6.2.17134.1
pnrpnsp.dll C:\Windows\System32\pnrpnsp.dll 6.2.17134.1
nlaapi.dll  C:\Windows\System32\nlaapi.dll  6.2.17134.1
winrnr.dll  C:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll  6.2.17134.1
wshbth.dll  C:\Windows\System32\wshbth.dll  6.2.17134.1
unicodedata.pyd C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\DLLs\unicodedata.pyd   0.0.0.0
_speedups.pyd   C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\markupsafe-0.23-py2.7-win-amd64.egg\markupsafe\_speedups.pyd 0.0.0.0
win32api.pyd    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\win32\win32api.pyd   2.7.218.0
pywintypes27.dll    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\pywintypes27.dll 2.7.218.0
_win32sysloader.pyd C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\win32\_win32sysloader.pyd    2.7.218.0
pythoncom27.dll C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\pythoncom27.dll  2.7.218.0
urlmon.dll  C:\Windows\System32\urlmon.dll  11.0.17134.165
iertutil.dll    C:\Windows\System32\iertutil.dll    11.0.17134.165
_imaging.pyd    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PIL\_imaging.pyd 0.0.0.0
_imagingft.pyd  C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PIL\_imagingft.pyd   0.0.0.0
pyexpat.pyd C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\DLLs\pyexpat.pyd   0.0.0.0
_gdalconst.pyd  C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\osgeo\_gdalconst.pyd 0.0.0.0
multiarray.pyd  C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\multiarray.pyd    0.0.0.0
libiomp5md.dll  C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\libiomp5md.dll    5.0.2014.710
umath.pyd   C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\umath.pyd 0.0.0.0
lapack_lite.pyd C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\lapack_lite.pyd 0.0.0.0
_umath_linalg.pyd   C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\_umath_linalg.pyd   0.0.0.0
fftpack_lite.pyd    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\numpy\fft\fftpack_lite.pyd   0.0.0.0
mtrand.pyd  C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\numpy\random\mtrand.pyd  0.0.0.0
_path.pyd   C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\_path.pyd 0.0.0.0
msvcp90.dll C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.9415_none_08e0c10ba840a28a\msvcp90.dll    9.0.30729.9415
_cntr.pyd   C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\_cntr.pyd 0.0.0.0
_contour.pyd    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\_contour.pyd  0.0.0.0
ft2font.pyd C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\ft2font.pyd   0.0.0.0
_png.pyd    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\_png.pyd  0.0.0.0
_image.pyd  C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\_image.pyd    0.0.0.0
_tri.pyd    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\_tri.pyd  0.0.0.0
_qhull.pyd  C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\_qhull.pyd    0.0.0.0
_backend_agg.pyd    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\_backend_agg.pyd 0.0.0.0
Qt.pyd  C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\Qt.pyd 0.0.0.0
QtHelp.pyd  C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\QtHelp.pyd 0.0.0.0
QtHelp4.dll C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\QtHelp4.dll  4.8.5.0
QtCLucene4.dll  C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\QtCLucene4.dll   4.8.5.0
QtMultimedia.pyd    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\QtMultimedia.pyd   0.0.0.0
QtMultimedia4.dll   C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\QtMultimedia4.dll    4.8.5.0
QtDeclarative.pyd   C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\QtDeclarative.pyd  0.0.0.0
QtDeclarative4.dll  C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\QtDeclarative4.dll   4.8.5.0
QtXmlPatterns4.dll  C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\QtXmlPatterns4.dll   4.8.5.0
QtOpenGL.pyd    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\QtOpenGL.pyd   0.0.0.0
QtScript.pyd    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\QtScript.pyd   0.0.0.0
QtScriptTools.pyd   C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\QtScriptTools.pyd  0.0.0.0
QtScriptTools4.dll  C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\QtScriptTools4.dll   4.8.5.0
QtSvg.pyd   C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\QtSvg.pyd  0.0.0.0
QtTest.pyd  C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\QtTest.pyd 0.0.0.0
QtTest4.dll C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\QtTest4.dll  4.8.5.0
QtXmlPatterns.pyd   C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\QtXmlPatterns.pyd  0.0.0.0
phonon.pyd  C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\phonon.pyd 0.0.0.0
phonon4.dll C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\phonon4.dll  4.4.0.0
QtDesigner.pyd  C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\QtDesigner.pyd 0.0.0.0
QtDesigner4.dll C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\QtDesigner4.dll  4.8.5.0
QAxContainer.pyd    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\QAxContainer.pyd   0.0.0.0
_psycopg.pyd    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\psycopg2\_psycopg.pyd    0.0.0.0
shfolder.dll    C:\Windows\System32\shfolder.dll    6.2.17134.1
_spatialite.pyd C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pyspatialite\_spatialite.pyd 0.0.0.0
_yaml.pyd   C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\_yaml.pyd    0.0.0.0
_ccallback_c.pyd    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scipy\_lib\_ccallback_c.pyd  0.0.0.0
_ufuncs.pyd C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scipy\special\_ufuncs.pyd    0.0.0.0
libifcoremd.dll C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\libifcoremd.dll   14.0.103.103
libmmd.dll  C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\libmmd.dll    14.0.0.3
_ufuncs_cxx.pyd C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scipy\special\_ufuncs_cxx.pyd    0.0.0.0
specfun.pyd C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scipy\special\specfun.pyd    0.0.0.0
_fblas.pyd  C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\_fblas.pyd  0.0.0.0
_flapack.pyd    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\_flapack.pyd    0.0.0.0
_flinalg.pyd    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\_flinalg.pyd    0.0.0.0
_solve_toeplitz.pyd C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\_solve_toeplitz.pyd 0.0.0.0
_decomp_update.pyd  C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\_decomp_update.pyd  0.0.0.0
cython_blas.pyd C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\cython_blas.pyd 0.0.0.0
cython_lapack.pyd   C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\cython_lapack.pyd   0.0.0.0
_comb.pyd   C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scipy\special\_comb.pyd  0.0.0.0
_ellip_harm_2.pyd   C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scipy\special\_ellip_harm_2.pyd  0.0.0.0
_odepack.pyd    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\_odepack.pyd 0.0.0.0
_quadpack.pyd   C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\_quadpack.pyd    0.0.0.0
vode.pyd    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\vode.pyd 0.0.0.0
_dop.pyd    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\_dop.pyd 0.0.0.0
lsoda.pyd   C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\lsoda.pyd    0.0.0.0
_sparsetools.pyd    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\_sparsetools.pyd    0.0.0.0
_csparsetools.pyd   C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\_csparsetools.pyd   0.0.0.0
_shortest_path.pyd  C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\csgraph\_shortest_path.pyd  0.0.0.0
_tools.pyd  C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\csgraph\_tools.pyd  0.0.0.0
_traversal.pyd  C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\csgraph\_traversal.pyd  0.0.0.0
_min_spanning_tree.pyd  C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\csgraph\_min_spanning_tree.pyd  0.0.0.0
_reordering.pyd C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\csgraph\_reordering.pyd 0.0.0.0
_iterative.pyd  C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\isolve\_iterative.pyd    0.0.0.0
_superlu.pyd    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\dsolve\_superlu.pyd  0.0.0.0
_arpack.pyd C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\eigen\arpack\_arpack.pyd 0.0.0.0
minpack2.pyd    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack2.pyd  0.0.0.0
_lbfgsb.pyd C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_lbfgsb.pyd   0.0.0.0
moduleTNC.pyd   C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\moduleTNC.pyd 0.0.0.0
_cobyla.pyd C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_cobyla.pyd   0.0.0.0
_slsqp.pyd  C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_slsqp.pyd    0.0.0.0
_minpack.pyd    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minpack.pyd  0.0.0.0
_group_columns.pyd  C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_group_columns.pyd    0.0.0.0
givens_elimination.pyd  C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_lsq\givens_elimination.pyd   0.0.0.0
_zeros.pyd  C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_zeros.pyd    0.0.0.0
_nnls.pyd   C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_nnls.pyd 0.0.0.0
_fitpack.pyd    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\_fitpack.pyd   0.0.0.0
dfitpack.pyd    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\dfitpack.pyd   0.0.0.0
_bspl.pyd   C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\_bspl.pyd  0.0.0.0
_ppoly.pyd  C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\_ppoly.pyd 0.0.0.0
interpnd.pyd    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\interpnd.pyd   0.0.0.0
ckdtree.pyd C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\ckdtree.pyd    0.0.0.0
_multiprocessing.pyd    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\DLLs\_multiprocessing.pyd  0.0.0.0
qhull.pyd   C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\qhull.pyd  0.0.0.0
_voronoi.pyd    C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\_voronoi.pyd   0.0.0.0
_distance_wrap.pyd  C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\_distance_wrap.pyd 0.0.0.0
_hausdorff.pyd  C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\_hausdorff.pyd 0.0.0.0
_stats.pyd  C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_stats.pyd   0.0.0.0
statlib.pyd C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\statlib.pyd  0.0.0.0
mvn.pyd C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\mvn.pyd  0.0.0.0
clbcatq.dll C:\Windows\System32\clbcatq.dll 2001.12.10941.16384
dataexchange.dll    C:\Windows\System32\dataexchange.dll    6.2.17134.1
dcomp.dll   C:\Windows\System32\dcomp.dll   6.2.17134.1
d3d11.dll   C:\Windows\System32\d3d11.dll   6.2.17134.112
dxgi.dll    C:\Windows\System32\dxgi.dll    6.2.17134.112
twinapi.appcore.dll C:\Windows\System32\twinapi.appcore.dll 6.2.17134.137
rmclient.dll    C:\Windows\System32\rmclient.dll    6.2.17134.81
TextInputFramework.dll  C:\Windows\System32\TextInputFramework.dll  6.2.17134.1
CoreMessaging.dll   C:\Windows\System32\CoreMessaging.dll   6.2.17134.165
CoreUIComponents.dll    C:\Windows\System32\CoreUIComponents.dll    6.2.17134.112
ntmarta.dll C:\Windows\System32\ntmarta.dll 6.2.17134.1
WinTypes.dll    C:\Windows\System32\WinTypes.dll    6.2.17134.112
FWPUCLNT.DLL    C:\Windows\System32\FWPUCLNT.DLL    6.2.17134.1
```

Is there a work around or fix for this issue?